# Got java.lang.NullPointerException every time

Tags: eclipse, cucumber, appium, appium-android

When I write scenario-2 in cucumber+eclipse+appium, there I'm getting null pointer exception.I using webElement and Remotewebdriver in place of Mobilelement and AndroidDriver.

1st try:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Choose']")).click();
```

2nd try:

```
tabs_list = driver.findElements(By.id("package:id/header_ll"));
        tabs_list.get(0).click();
```

Where I'm not able to click on the view, here only getting Null pointer exception

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please share the code where you declared the `tabs-list` and the scope of that variable.

Comment: Share the error log so that i can help you

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace and the code it is pointing to, as that will provide information on what is causing the NPE